# Countable intersection of open dense subsets in a locally compact space is dense

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a locally compact space and, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $U_n$ be an open dense subset of $X$. Prove that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ is dense in $X$.

**My idea** I have to prove that $ X= \overline{\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n}$, let $x \in X$ and let $U \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $x \in U$, since $U_n$ is dense in $X$ we have $\overline{U_n}=X$, so $x \in \overline{U_n}$ and $U \cap U_n \neq \emptyset$, and we have that $X$ is locally compact so there is $V \in \mathcal{T}$ and a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $x \in V$ and $V \subset K$. I don't know how to use the fact that $K$ is compact

Comment: Have you seen the proof of the Baire category theorem for compact sets?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No haven't. I didn't find it

Comment: Do you know that if $K_0\supseteq K_1\supseteq K_2\supseteq\ldots\;$, and $K_0$ is compact, then $\bigcap_{n\ge 0}K_n\ne\varnothing$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes I know that

Comment: Okay: that’s just the tool that you need, and I’ve given a pointer in the right direction in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Choose $V_0\in\mathcal{T}$ so that $x\in V_0\subseteq\operatorname{cl}V_0\subseteq U\cap U_0$. Given $V_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, there is a $V_{n+1}\in\mathcal{T}$ such that $$x\in V_{n+1}\subseteq\operatorname{cl}V_{n+1}\subseteq V_n\cap U_{n+1}\,.$$ Now consider $\bigcap_{n\ge 0}\operatorname{cl}V_n$.